# capture image is not working properly.?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

Hi I am very new to developing iOS application please help me. i am facing a problem regarding capturing image by using `UIImagePicker`. I have integrated hip mob app in to our application.

In that window i want to show a `UIButton` so that the user click on that `UIButton` should capture the image. when i click on the button its throwing an message as (whose view is not in the window hierarchy!).

I think this happens due to this chat window. here is my code snippet.!

```
[[HMService sharedService] openChat:self withSetup:^(HMChatViewController * controller)
{
 controller.chatDelegate = self;
 controller.chatView.receivedMessageFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0];
 controller.navigationBarHidden = YES;
 UIView * viewObjForVehicleDetails = [[UIView alloc]init];
 UIButton * btnForCaputrePhoto = [[UIButton alloc]init];
 [btnForCaputrePhoto addTarget:self action:@selector(CapturePhotoImage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  btnForCaputrePhoto.frame = CGRectMake(55, 90, 103, 85);
 [controller.chatView addSubview:viewObjForVehicleDetails];
 [viewObjForVehicleDetails addSubview:btnForCaputrePhoto];
 [[controller.chatView table] registerClass:[ChatTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ReuseChatTableViewCell"]; 
} 


 -(void)CapturePhotoImage
{
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:nil];

}   


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Thanks in Advance.!

Comment: is the image picker is showing ? or it is crashing

Comment: Thanks For your reply..! no its not showing image picker, i tested in device so its not crashing. i think i am using hipmob controller to that i am adding button so its not navigating imagePickerView

Comment: you were add the self.view add subview of viewObjForVehicleDetails

Comment: i want show this image on that controller not in the view so i added this  viewObjForVehicleDetails to controller not to view. thats why this issue occurred..@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: How to add image picker to other controller instead of self.view..?@Anbu.Karthik, @Vizllx

Comment: i have a chat window on that window i added a tableview on click on tableview cell we will show an view with button on click on button we  need to capture an image. all this should be on same controller.!@

Comment: same controller means that HMChatViewController

Comment: That means you have a chat window -> tableview->on click on tableview cell ->view with button is shown!This much is working fine! But just the button click is not calling UIImagePicker? right?

Comment: yes. What i am trying to do is.! @JennyJose

Answer (score 1):

*First be sure you are using the following delegate in your view controller*

```
<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

*Secondly use this line to show the ImagePicker:-*

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

**Alternative Way:-**

```
[self.view addSubview:imagePicker.cameraOverlayView]
```

Comment: Yes i have given these delegate methods and i also given [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES]; to my code even though there is no change. Its showing same message [ whose view is not in the window hierarchy!]

Comment: @AppDeveloper- Check the alternative answer.

Comment: i have checked this alternative Way. i dint receive any message. and i dint get the imagePicker as well i think that 3 rd party controller overlap this view so this image picker might be display under this controller

Comment: can u just check waht is the  imagePicker frame, or just NSLog(@"%@",imagePicker); and log the details here.

Comment: I have called this imagePicker method in view didload. its showing imagePicker, before this button clicked. and it's not displaying when i click on button.. so this might be the problem of adding this image picker to controller.! @Vizllx

Answer (score 1):

Change the method declaration as follows

```
- (IBAction) CapturePhotoImage:(id)sender
{
    NSLog("Called");
}
```

And the method call "CapturePhotoImage" as CapturePhotoImage:

```
 [btnForCaputrePhoto addTarget:self action:@selector(CapturePhotoImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: no its not showing image Picker, and throwing an message as whose view is not in the window hierarchy!